# Prove that a tournament is irreducible if and only if it is strongly connected

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

If a graph is irreducible, by definition there will be no source or sink and it will be strongly connected.

Is my proof above good and how do I prove the converse?

Comment: Your proof is lacking in... existence.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a definition of irreducible, as not everyone is familiar with it.

Now, why does no source or sink imply strongly connected ?  I don't believe this direction of the proof is complete without an explanation for this (or known results).

As for the other direction, suppose the tournament is not irreducible.  Then you can partition the vertices into two sets $A, B$ such that no arc goes from $B$ to $A$ (if we use the same definition hopefully).  Now, can the tournament be strongly connected ?